# Slow motion of a spherical object on an blunt slant obstacle

Tags: iphone, box2d, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d

In cocos2d environment and box2D when an spherical object falls on a blunt slant obstacle, it moves really slowly, that's nauseating, if you have coded to not to have any interaction with world while object is in motion. Is there any way to get rid of this slow motion of object?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what is happening, and what your desired result is? A quick picture or sketch would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that your slant really is not steep enough as Aku says, but it's more likely you flagged the object for fixed rotation, meaning it's not rolling down the slope, but rather sliding against friction. This makes it much slower, and if the slope is not steep enough, can halt it entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Physics dictates that when you put a ball on a slant, it tends to roll. If it's a small slant, it rolls slowly. It's a matter of certain physics applied to certain conditions.

To get the effect you want, you have to either change the conditions...

- for example, increase the slope to get it to roll off quicker

... or change the physics...

- for example, add more friction (this could be conditional; only added if the slope is very small).